# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not SvltePhoneProxy

Tags: android

When I opened my android phone, it notified me that com.android.phone crashed. and I can not go into the system.

The Error message are as follows:

```
05-01 00:03:02.654 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 435
05-01 00:03:03.154 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 436
05-01 00:03:03.655 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 437
05-01 00:03:03.687 3586-3586/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-01 00:03:03.948 3586-3625/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-01 00:03:03.978 3586-3628/? E/DcSwitchStateMachine-0: DctController is not ready
05-01 00:03:03.989 1060-1224/system_process E/ConnectivityService: Failed to find Messenger in unregisterNetworkFactory
05-01 00:03:04.108 3586-3586/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.phone, PID: 3586
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not SvltePhoneProxy!
at com.mediatek.internal.telephony.ltedc.svlte.SvlteUtils.getSvltePhoneProxy(SvlteUtils.java:146)
at com.mediatek.internal.telephony.RadioCapabilitySwitchUtil.getMainCapabilityPhoneId(RadioCapabilitySwitchUtil.java:614)
at com.mediatek.internal.telephony.ImsSwitchController.handleMessage(ImsSwitchController.java:463)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
05-01 00:03:04.156 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 438
05-01 00:03:04.656 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 439
05-01 00:03:05.157 348-714/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] Fail to connect . retry count: 440
```